# References in VB.net project

Tags: vb.net

The problem I have at work is that I have to re-add references every time I get a new project from SVN.  I'm trying to understand the process that the team need to follow to stop this happening.

The goal is so that anybody in the team can get the latest code and have a successful build.  However, we always seem to have issues with references missing.

As a general rule we have a "libs" folder within the project and reference anything we need from inside that. I'm not sure if this is the best approach?

I've just done a test by getting the latest version of a site from SVN. This particular site looks like it must have been set up as a website rather than a web project as there is no vbproj file.  I had a few references missing.  I went into the property pages of the site to check the locations of the references.  I thought the paths may be specific to somebody's machines but the references didn't even seem to be added.  So I added the references that I needed (They were in the "libs" folder).  Then everything built successfully but I had nothing marked to check in so what file actually changed when I added the references?

I think the problem may be a combination of web project verses websites and how visual studio treats them differently and how we are using the "libs" folder.  Thoughts?

Comment: Why aren't you using project references within the solution?

Comment: In the different companies I've worked for, we have a centralized *repository* (basically a folder on a network drive, that gets pulled down to our machines via a simple application) to a simple folder (aka `C:\references`). Then we also keep our projects in a simple location (aka `C:\projects`). This keeps everything pretty easy and simple to fix when broken between projects.

Comment: Generally for asp.net website projects you want to put your binary references in the `bin` directory.  Also when you pull down your source can you verify that the references were present in the `web.config`.  This isn't a problem in website application projects as your project file will contain the reference data.

Comment: I've just tried creating a web project instead of a website so that I can see the proj file.  If I add dll's to the libs folder it seems to use a relative path.  So looks like setting the projects up as web projects is probably the best way to go in the first instance.  Think the reason my original test failed was because of no proj file and the references to the .dll's were not in the config file.

Answer (score 1):

You have two points here

- where to keep references in multi-project solution

  One way that will never fail you is to have a `bin` folder (aka `libs` - I really don't know why would people call it anything other than `bin`) ... so... to have a bin folder in the same location as solution, while projects would be in their separate sub folders.

`--Solution Folder
  -- .sln
  -- bin
  -- Project1 Folder
  -- Project2 Folder`

Now, in your bin you keep all `.dll` files, including ones you build and third party as well. Your projects will be referencing from this `bin` and build output will go into this bin. This bin should be part of version control. It is not recommended to check-in *your* DLLs into this bin but do check-in third party DLLs. Also notice, referencing from "under solution" will create reference with relative path - this is important.

- how to deal with references in Web Site Project (vs Web Site Application)

  This is not unusual that out of the version control you don't have references in your website. Here is what you need to do. For each DLL that Web Site Project references, you need to create `DllName.dll.Refresh` file under `WebsiteProject-Bin` in which you will set relative path to that dll. `.refresh` files should be checked-in. Once you build your libraries, only then you can build your website. It will pull all the DLLs you need to run it. With this setup, you now only need to make a virtual directory and point it to your WebsiteProject folder - you should have a running website.

Third point

- Nuget

  If your project(s) use `nuget` packages, create `packages` folder under your Solution folder and point there all `nuget.config` in your projects. This way you will have one central `nuget` repository, which will make your life easy.

If you follow these guidelines, you shouldn't have any problems building and deploying after `Get Latest` from version control. Just make sure that all existing references are relative.