# Configuring a shared output directory for ~20 projects in the same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Using C#.NET MVC 4 Web App - I'm trying to optimize a solution's build time. Right now it takes about 5 minutes to rebuild the solution that contains the MVC web project plus ~15 library projects that the web app references. Some of the library projects reference other library projects that we managed plus third party DLLs like Autofac and Automapper.

All projects (web app, libraries, unit and integration tests) have `CopyLocal = False` for each reference. All projects have their output directory set to `..\bin\` which is a folder located at the root of the solution (outside of the individual projects).

Doing a solution rebuild works without errors. However, when I launch the startup app (the MVC web app) using F5 (Debug > Start Debugging) I get the following compilation error

> Warning: C:\tfs\src\fosm\MvcApp\Global.asax: ASP.NET runtime error: There is no build provider registered for the extension '.asax'. You can register one in the  section in machine.config or web.config. Make sure is has a BuildProviderAppliesToAttribute attribute which includes the value 'Web' or 'All'.
>
> Error: Could not load type 'MvcApp.Global'.   C:\temp\global.asax

Here's my Global.asax.

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="MvcApp.Global" Language="C#" %>
```

How can I fix this problem? All of the resources I have been reading that recommend using a shared bin folder mention that "most" references need to be set to `CopyLocal = False`, but they don't go into details on identifying or listing the references that should be left to `CopyLocal = True`.

Here are a few resources that I have been using to setup a shared bin folder to improve build time.

http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/momchil-mitev's-blog/2014/05/16/how-to-speed-up-the-build-of-your-solution-in-visual-studio

http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2010/12/01/Slash-your-ASPNET-compileload-time.aspx

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2006/06/30/part-1-of-3-creating-sub-projects-in-iis-with-web-application-projects/

Comment: Don't press F5, you don't need to.  Instead install IIS locally.  Setup a website and map the IIS Physical Path directly to your project folder from your code.  You might need to add the app pool user to NTFS permissions on your project folders.  Once you get the site loading in IIS from your project folders, you can just attach your debugger (ctrl + alt + p) to w3wp.exe.

To test a code change, merely build the one dll that changed, and the app pool will automatically cycle, or live reload the dll when it detects a bin change.

Comment: Since I started using IIS for debugging, I don't use f5 or iis express anymore... Using F5 and IIS Express works great for little tiny projects, but it's so incredibly slow for large projects, IIS is better for large projects.

Comment: Also, if you have multiple web apps, leave the app pool users as Application Pool Identity.  That way you know which w3wp.exe to attach to.  The user will be "App Pool\AppPoolNameHere"

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/31095864/1704458. Also, why `CopyLocal = False`. What is the point?  Only don't copy local framework dlls. Remove project references - do dll references. I feel you building too many projects. Separate web project into different solution as well.